# Fix bar graph made with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

So, I would like to make a chart where on the X axis I have the families and on the Y axis the number of times each family appears within my dataset. I imported the dataset using the pandas library and using the matplotlib library I tried to make this chart, but it came out with the axes inverted and also with the elements too close together. Here is the code I used

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ornitologia = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/mjoao/OneDrive/Documentos/Coleção_MNRJ/Ornitologia/ornitologia.xlsx')
familias = ornitologia['FAMÍLIA']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
eixo = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

indice = range(len(familias))

eixo.bar(indice, familias)
eixo.set_title('Lotes por famílias', fontsize=15, pad=10)
eixo.set_xlabel('Famílias',fontsize=15)
eixo.set_ylabel('Lotes', fontsize=15)
```

[image: Graph that resulted from the code]

I hope I can get the data on the right axes and with a better distance between them for a really useful visualization of the graph.

Comment: You could try `ornitologia.value_counts('FAMÍLIA').plot.bar(rot=90)` to first count how many times each family appears, and then create a bar plot.

Comment: This helped, but the graphic came with the names close to one of the other

Comment: You could try a wider `figsize` (`figsize=(20,4)`?). And a smaller font (`eixo.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)`?).

Comment: I use figsize=(5,12) and all the names are better in the image, but i still want to invert the axis

Comment: You want horizontal bars?  `ornitologia.value_counts('FAMÍLIA').plot.barh()`?

Answer (score 0):

> but it came out with the axes inverted

Simply switch the `bar()` parameters to

```py
eixo.bar(familias, indice)
```

As expected, you will have the families along the X axis and the "number of times each family appears" along the Y axis.

> and also with the elements too close together

This is due to the short width set for the figure: `plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))`. Try increasing the first value until you reach the desired look.

You might also want to play with the `xticks` labels rotation if you don't want the string names to be overlapping.

```
eixo.set_xticklabels(familias, rotation=90)
```

Here is the type of figure you can obtain (using randomly generated values)

```py
# [...]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))  # Increase figure width
eixo = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

eixo.bar(familias, indice)  # Invert families and indice

eixo.set_title('Lotes por famílias', fontsize=15, pad=10)
eixo.set_xlabel('Famílias',fontsize=15)
eixo.set_ylabel('Lotes', fontsize=15)

eixo.set_xticklabels(familias, rotation=90)  # Display the xticks labels vertically
```

[image]